# Как в экселе сделать автозаполнение?

Tags: excel

Не знаю, как называется эта функция, но предположим ячейка А1="А", ячейка В1="45", А2="Б", В2="48" и так весь алфавит. Нужно, при вводе в ячейке С1 символа Б чтоб в ячейке D1 отобразился ответ = 48.

То есть каждая буква алфавита имеет свое значение (вариант), и при вводе буквы чтоб в нужной ячейке показался вариант.

Comment: @Аваз Бенджамин, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Функция *ВПР* поможет:

```
=ВПР(C1;A1:B30;2;)
```